# User Identity Framework asp.net Identity and LDAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap, openldap

Currently, my boss as me to create a user identity system for Individual Account under .NET platform. At the beginning, I prefer to use ASP.net Identity framework, but my boss advise LDAP. I am not sure which one is better or not.

Below is basic requirement.

1. support millions of users
2. support different Groups of user (e.g. we have 3 different groups, General Practice, Public clients, staff)
3. Email Verified for registration.
4. External Login such as facebook.

Can you let me know which one is better?

Comment: Are they mutually exclusive? Can't you have your ASP.NET Identity and supplement it with LDAP?

Comment: I am trying to find the way to do it. Unfortunately, I cannot find any solution at the moment

Comment: You just just implement UserStore and RoleStore similar how it's doen in the following project: https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet-Server-Template (though it's uses SQL database, but you would replace it with LDAP)

Answer (score 0):

Due to your requirements Asp.Net Identity is the way to go. It provides all as built-in. Plus it's more flexible and new technology.

I think about why your boss advice LDAP. To me, only reason can be to use only one username and password in company and it's Domain User Account (Active Directory).

If so i am in a similar situation. I think to use both of them. For example when a user will be created in Identity i will create it in Active Directory also. So users will use same account in Computers and Applications and i will have Identity's all advantages and will use them in applications. Active Directory will include only a copy of user info (not full copy just needed).